# How to correctly install umbraco 7.10 or 8 getting stuck on db configuration

Tags: installation, umbraco, umbraco8

I am trying to install and configure Umbraco 8.
The NuGet installs umbracoCms well then I run the app to configure the database (custom DB).

And it crashes displaying:

```
Error during installation

See the log for full details (logs can typically be found in the App_Data\Logs folder)
```

The log doesn't tell e much:

```
{"@t":"2019-04-24T04:04:00.1230739Z","@mt":"An error occurred in InstallStatus trying to check upgrades","@l":"Error","@x":"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Install.InstallHelper.GetDbProviderString(ISqlContext sqlContext)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Install.InstallHelper.InstallStatus(Boolean isCompleted, String errorMsg)","SourceContext":"Umbraco.Web.Install.InstallHelper","ProcessId":1180,"ProcessName":"iisexpress","ThreadId":13,"AppDomainId":3,"AppDomainAppId":"LMW3SVC2ROOT","MachineName":"Machine1","Log4NetLevel":"ERROR","HttpRequestNumber":4,"HttpRequestId":"{requestguid}"}
```

The DB connestring is correct, the database tables are getting created although from the error message I am not able to figure out it's a problem with DB or the app.

The same things happened with Umbraco 7.10.

I am running the project on .NET 4.7.2, in VS 15.9.11 and MSSQL 2016

Comment: Did you fill in the connection string in the web.config before running the installer (if so: you should not)? Step by step NuGet install instructions are here, make sure to follow those: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Install/install-umbraco-with-nuget

Comment: Yes, of course lol... the connection string is being verified before the setup starts running anyway so it wouldn't let me progress if I didn't do it. It's not the first time I am installing umbraco, I never had problem setting up the database. @sebastiaan